# Where is my mistake?

Tags: c, wiring

I am trying to run a c program which will wait for me to hit a key on a 4x4 keypad and then display the number I have hit. The program I have bit runs but ends just as soon as I start it and I can't find my mistake.

```
 #include <wiringPi.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define COL1     11
 #define COL2     10
 #define COL3     6
 #define COL4     5
 #define ROW1     4
 #define ROW2     3
 #define ROW3     2
 #define ROW4     1

 #define DET      0

 int colnum;
 int rownum;

 int keyinterrupt (void)
 {
      int col[] = {COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4};
      int row[] = {ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4};
      int reset;
      for(colnum = 0; colnum++; colnum < 4)
      {
           for(reset = 0; reset++; reset < 4)
           {
                digitalWrite(col[reset], 0);
           }

           digitalWrite(col[colnum], 1);

           for(rownum = 0; rownum++; rownum < 4)
           {
                if(digitalRead(row[rownum]))
                {return 0;}
           }
      }
 }

 int main (void)
 {
      pinMode(COL1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(COL4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ROW1, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW2, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW3, INPUT);
      pinMode(ROW4, INPUT);

      if(wiringPiISR (DET, INT_EDGE_RISING, &keyinterrupt) < 0)
      {
           printf("Unable to setup ISR");
           return 1;
      }

      while(1)
      {
           while(!DET)
           {
                delay(1);
           }

           printf("The key pressed was at Col:%i Row:%i", colnum, rownum);
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Add "\n" at the and of your `"Unable to setup ISR"` string to printf() and it be more clear on why your program ends its execution. Also note that your `while(!DET)` loop is an infinite loop since `DET` is defined to be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is possibly segfaulting because have swapped the loop and post-loop statements while the function does not return a meaningful value. Consider:

```
int keyinterrupt (void)
 {
      int col[] = {COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4};
      int row[] = {ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4};
      int reset;
      for(colnum = 0; colnum++; colnum < 4)
      {
           // ...
      }
 }
```

`colnum++` returns `0`, so the contents of the loop is never executed. I guess you meant:

```
for (colnum = 0; colnum < 4; colnum++)
```

This function does not return any value. If you enabled compiler warnings (`cc -Wall -Wextra`), it would have warned you.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this mistake. All my for loops have the conditions switched on them. However, the program still didn't perform the task.

Comment: @Marmstrong What "does not not work"? Any error messages? Is the program segfaulting?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous reply. The program compiles with no errors but when it is run it just ends. It should wait for a keystroke and then display it, then wait for another keystroke.

Comment: No output at all? Try adding `puts("....");` on lines for debugging, substituting `....` for your debug message (e.g. `puts("BEFORE digitalWrite");` or `printf("BEFORE digitalWrite: %i:%i\n", colnum, reset)